# HTML table editable cells

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a simple way to make a html table editable? I have a simple table with 2 headers and 4 tds and a edit button at the end of each row using a bootstrap MUI class. Is there a way to make my table editable without changing everything? What I need is I click my cell and edit the cell get the new info and when I click the edit button I can pass to the backend.

Table :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>1</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>1</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>2</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>2</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>3</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>3</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I just need to know how to make the cell editable and get all the info of the cell edited and even those not edited in the same row.

Comment: I looked for datatables, i made a edit with a prompt but i don't want to do it with a prompt I need to edit on cell

Answer (score 0):

To edit a text you need to place inputs  to your table cells.
So you can make like this:
by clicking on a table cell, you actually clicked on an input where you can edit your text. That's the best way to do it.

Like so:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    width: 25px;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'><input type="text" value="1"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'><input type="text" value="1"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'><input type="text" value="2"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'><input type="text" value="2"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'><input type="text" value="3"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'><input type="text" value="3"></td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
    <td>editButton</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```